# Fetching fields from router probe using scapy in python

Tags: python, scapy

I am using scapy for sniffing packets. I have got my router in monitoring mode so I can catch the probe request. After getting the probe request I am fetching ssid, rssi, manufacture name, time, mac address. So is there any method I can get more fields like channel, model name, association state? In wireshark, I am getting all these field but how to get these fields in scapy?

```
from scapy.all import *
import logging
import logging.handlers

PROBE_REQUEST_TYPE=0
PROBE_REQUEST_SUBTYPE=4

WHITELIST = ['18:dc:56:f0:40:40','34:a3:95:b1:2b:d9','48:13:7e:57:ae:b6','98:0c:a5:17:7d:2d'] # Replace this with your phone's MAC address
#WHITELIST = ['00:00:00:00:00:00',] # Replace this with your phone's MAC address

def PacketHandler(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        #if pkt.type==PROBE_REQUEST_TYPE and pkt.subtype == PROBE_REQUEST_SUBTYPE and ( pkt.addr2.lower() in WHITELIST or pkt.addr2.upper() in WHITELIST):
        if pkt.type==PROBE_REQUEST_TYPE and pkt.subtype == PROBE_REQUEST_SUBTYPE:
            PrintPacket(pkt)

def PrintPacket(pkt):
    print "Probe Request Captured:"
    try:
        extra = pkt.notdecoded
    except:
        extra = None
    if extra!=None:
        signal_strength = -(256-ord(extra[-4:-3]))
    else:
        signal_strength = -100
        print "No signal strength found"    
    #print "Time: %s Target: %s Source: %s SSID: %s RSSi: %d "%(pkt.time,pkt.addr3,pkt.addr2,pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info,signal_strength)
    print "Time: %s  Source: %s SSID: %s RSSi: %d "%(pkt.time,pkt.addr3,pkt.addr2,pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info,signal_strength)
    str = "%s,%s,%s,%s,%d\n"%(pkt.time,pkt.addr2,pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info,signal_strength)
    #f = open('log.txt',"a")
    #f.write(str)
    WriteToFile(str)

def WriteToFile(str):
    my_logger = logging.getLogger('agentlogger')
    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('tplink3020.log', mode='a', maxBytes=1000, backupCount=10, encoding=None, delay=0)
    my_logger.addHandler(handler)
    my_logger.warn(str)

def main():
    from datetime import datetime
    print "[%s] Starting scan"%datetime.now()
    print "Scanning :"
    WriteToFile("Hello")
    #print "\n".join(mac for mac in WHITELIST)
    sniff(iface=sys.argv[1],prn=PacketHandler)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()`
```